Can I safely uninstall gdm3 after switching to lightdm?
Since Ubuntu 24.04 the login screen is not shown as long as my external HDMI monitor was plugged in. I always had to unplug it, login, replug the monitor. I found out that this seems to be a bug in gdm3, so I installed lightdm and set it as default. Now I can login without having to unplug-login-replug.
Since lightdm works well, I wanted to remove gdm3 with sudo apt purge gdm3, however this tells me that gdm3* ubuntu-desktop* ubuntu-desktop-minimal* would be removed. This sounds rather critical to me. If I try simulating sudo apt -s purge ubuntu-desktop it would basically remove "everything".
Is it even possible to completly (e.g. removing alternatives) switch to lightdm on Ubuntu? I'd like to have a very clean system with only the stable packages I actually use.

Can you post the actual output you get for sudo apt purge gdm3?

Don't forget GDM3 is the GNOME Display Manager, and makes calls to the GNOME desktop libraries, which is why it's linked (https://packages.ubuntu.com/noble/gdm3); plus Ubuntu Desktop relies on GNOME.  This is not Ubuntu specific, but a connection built into GNOME.  Are you using Ubuntu Desktop and thus GNOME?   FYI:  I have Ubuntu Desktop (GNOME) installed on this box & use sddm myself.. but I still wouldn't remove gdm3 as I don't see it would achieve much at all of benefit even if accomplished.

Clearly sudo apt purge gdm3 is not the right command to use to safely uninstall gdm3. These commands would be a better way of doing it.
apt --simulate remove gdm3 
sudo apt autoremove

If the results of apt --simulate remove gdm3 look OK, you can uninstall gdm3 with sudo apt remove gdm3 .
